# 301 redirect to correct url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have a lot of incorrect bad links and want to 301 redirect them to the correct one, the correct url are as follows:

> Blockquote http://www.domain.com/string-video_string.html

the back links are pointing to:

> Blockquote http://www.domain.com/string_string.html

any possible way to 301 redirect the wrong back links to the correct links?

Thank you in adance

Comment: This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665672/using-regular-expression-in-htaccess-for-301-redirects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^_-]+)_(.+)$ /$1-video_$2
```

Comment: thanks but i just edited the question  because i did not explain it right, the  /folder-name/ is not always the same it changes depending on the url...

Comment: Hope you realize rewrite rule has no magic to figure out folder name

Comment: and how would to just 301 to redirest from the wrong links which are

http://www.domain.com/string_string.html to http://www.domain.com/string-video_string.html once i got them there i think can manage somehow to get them properly

Comment: yes there are more rules in htaccess the error is 404

Comment: Thank you so much for your time i have figured out with php

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to redirect (in which method; PHP, htaccess, etc.) you have some options.

I assume you're seeing 404 errors when users are trying to get to the links from an external source, like a search engine.

If that's the case, you can easily generate the code you need for which ever method you choose using this website:
http://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/redirect-generator.htm

Make sure that you correctly format the URL's you want to redirect and it should work fine.

If you want to make sure your SEO issues get fixed, you should create a robots.txt file and place it in the root directory of your site (usually where the index file is) - and follow the instructions from this site: http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/ to de-index the bad links from the search engine. You may also want to create and submit (or resubmit) XML site maps to the search engines your users use most.