# Redirect with htaccess directory/page to directory under different domain

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect whole website from one domain to another with the exact extention, BUT only all pages in specific directory should be redirected to another directory on new website.
`http://www.website.com/dir/page-123` (all pages starting with "`page-`" to `http://www.newwebsite/dir/`. 
Tried many options, nothing works.
Please shot the ideas

Comment: @Jon Lin saw you helped with similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665672/using-regular-expression-in-htaccess-for-301-redirects  Can you take a look please on my question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir/page-([\d]+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newwebsite/dir [R=301,NC]
```

if your page have extension please use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir/page-([\d]+).exe$
```

replace **exe** with your extension.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, tried, but it redirects to: `http://www.newwebsite/dir/page-`. For example I tried to check `http://www.myoldwebsite/dir/page-1234` and it redirected me to `http://www.mynewwebsite/dir/page-1234`, but I need it to be redirected to `http://www.newwebsite/dir`

Comment: please check i've tested it

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek gurjar, used edited code, but it returns Not Found on old website and doesn't redirect to newwebsite at all :(

Comment: I tried to use only your rule, but it doesn't work. Then, I tried to use this: `RewriteRule ^dir/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ http://www.oldwebsite.com/dir/ RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newwebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]` But the last rule takes control on first one and redirects also /dir/page-* pages to exact page on newwebsite.

Comment: please try i've tested it with all of your present condition!