# Creating redirect rule in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301

Just made some changes in my site, now my link  site.com/some-page  looks like  site.com/listing/some-page

So, question is how I can create a redirect rule which will redirect to /listing/

Answer (score 0):

This should answer all your questions regarding moving a wordpress site: https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You can setup redirect through .htaccess or use a plugin.

Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

There are a number of references to .htaccess redirection for wordpress within stackoverflow.

.htaccess:
[Using regular expression in htaccess for 301 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665672/using-regular-expression-in-htaccess-for-301-redirects?r=SearchResults)